# Is there a specific UML diagram for describing the content of a dataset (folders and files)?

Tags: directory, uml

I am collecting a dataset containing numerous signals contained in several folders. Is there a UML diagram that I can use to best describe the datasets content?

I tried to look online for a solution, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can use (almost) any kind of diagram since there is (almost) no limitation on what element can be shown where. However, to show a package structure you can use a package diagram (see also https://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams-overview.html). You can either enlarge package icons so can nest them graphically (which after a few levels might become tough) or you use the nesting relation and place the packages in a tree-like structure.

Comment: Thank you! I 'll definitely check that out!